# Can BannedSymbols.txt be added solution wide not on each project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, roslyn-code-analysis, .net-4.8

I'm trying to configure BannedApiAnalyzers for my C# .NET Framework solution (4.x).

The documentation indicates that to enable this analyzer I need to add the components at project level. This seems crazily inefficient for a project that has hundreds of projects. Is there a way to apply these rulesets at solution level?

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers/BannedApiAnalyzers.Help.md

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved with putting the BannedSymbols.txt in your solution root folder then creating a Directory.Build.props file with the following content.

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.6.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.props" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.6.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers.3.3.3\build\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers.props" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers.3.3.3\build\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers.props')" />
 <ItemGroup>
   <AdditionalFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)BannedSymbols.txt">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     <Link>BannedSymbols.txt</Link>
   </AdditionalFiles>
 </ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers.3.3.3\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers.dll" />
    <Analyzer Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers.3.3.3\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BannedApiAnalyzers.dll" />
    <Analyzer Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.6.0.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll" />
    <Analyzer Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.6.0.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

A C# project can be referenced from a different solution. From this point of view, it might be better to use `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)` rather than `$(SolutionDir)` in your `Directory.Build.props`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)BannedSymbols.txt"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/34268d1bb9370c7b01c742303a895a99daf10d6a/src/Features/Directory.Build.targets#L4C14-L6